# GWT PopupPanel just appearing once

Tags: gwt, popuppanel

I`m using GWT-Popup-Panel with the following code:

private static class MyPopup extends PopupPanel {

```
        public MyPopup() {
          // PopupPanel's constructor takes 'auto-hide' as its boolean parameter.
          // If this is set, the panel closes itself automatically when the user
          // clicks outside of it.
          super(true);

          // PopupPanel is a SimplePanel, so you have to set it's widget property to
          // whatever you want its contents to be.
          setWidget(new Label("Click outside of this popup to close it"));

        }
      }



public void onModuleLoad() {

     final Button b1 = new Button("About");
        b1.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
          public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            final MyPopup g = new MyPopup();
            g.setWidget(RootPanel.get("rightagekeyPanel"));
            g.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PopupPanel.PositionCallback() {
                public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {
                  g.setPopupPosition(b1.getAbsoluteLeft(), b1.getAbsoluteTop());
                  g.setAutoHideEnabled(true);
                }
              });

            g.setVisible(true);
            g.setWidth("500px");
            g.setHeight("500px");

            g.show();

          }
        });
```

It does appear when clicking Button b1, but not when clicking it the second time. What is wrong?

Comment: Why are you calling `setWidget()` inside `onClick()` when you are already calling it in the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one popup, outside of your `ClickHandler`, at the same level as your `Button`. You also don't need that `PositionCallback` to center your popup. You can just call `g.center()` to show it and center it. It's a known issue on the GWT support pages that it won't center properly if you don't set a width to it. It will center properly if you give your popup a proper width.

**The reason it doesn't show again** is because you remove the widget inside `RootPanel.get("rightagekeyPanel")` and put it into your popup. It is no longer there the next time you try to do it.

A widget can only be in one place at a time, so if you remove it from its parent, keep track of it with a variable or something, so you can re-use it. Otherwise, you must re-instantiate the widget.

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    final Button b1 = new Button("About");
    final MyPopup g = new MyPopup(); //create only one instance and reuse it.
    g.setAutoHideEnabled(true);
    g.setSize("500px", "500px"); //sets width AND height


    b1.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

            g.setWidget(RootPanel.get("rightagekeyPanel"));//DON'T DO THIS.

            g.center();//will show it and center it.
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just say in my case I had to add some widget to make the PopUpPanel appear. Try using a label to make sure the Popup is showing.

```
    PopupPanel popup = new PopupPanel();    
    popup.setVisible(true);
    popup.center();
    popup.show();
    popup.setWidth("500px");
    popup.setHeight("500px");
    popup.add(new Label("Test"));
```